# How to auto-load older Facebook messages in the Chrome Javascript console and deal with "Temporary Failure" error?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, message

in a Facebook message conversation, my goal is to get all the messages in one single page, in order to save the complete conversation in one file. 
I'm not satisfied with downloading the Facebook data because the file provided by Facebook in that case doesn't contain the graphics included in the messages, and worst, the messages for one person are not shown in a strict chronological order.

So I'm using a trick on Google Chrome, using the Javascript console. (Ctrl + Shift + J) and the "mobile" version of Facebook.  https://m.facebook.com
Once I'm on a particular message thread, the page displays the last few messages, and a link on top of them allows us to load earlier messages. It is labelled "See Older Messages..." and has an ID named "see_older".

Then on the console, I input this javascript code :

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById('see_older')
        .getElementsByClassName('content')[0].click();
}, 1000);
```

This works fine, the message page gets filled progressively with previous message, but randomly, Facebook returns an error.
The error says "**Temporary Failure. There was a temporary error, please try again.**"

In the HTML source code :

```
<div class="_55wr acr apm abb" data-sigil="marea">
<span class="mfsm">Temporary Failure</span>
<br />There was a temporary error, please try again.</div>
```

The manual solution is simply to click on "Back" on the browser, then wait that the page reloads the previous messages, and launch the javascript command again.
It can be very tedious.

I was wondering if there was something that could be done in Javascript to detect the occurrence of that error page, make a programmatic Back command on the browser, and when the previous page is ready, execute the script again.
This way the whole process could be completely unattended until the message thread reaches its beginning.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Ed,

This is a brilliant solution to the problem, and exactly what I've been looking for for the last few days. Did you manage to solve the problem outlined in this post? If not, how reliable is the current piece of code at loading all of the messages on a thread?

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason it needs to be on the mobile version? Doesn't the web version also have the same "See Older Messages" link?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping information from Facebook is against the Facebook [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you shouldn't do it.

If you wish you read a users message please use Facebook Platform by creating an app and creating a submission for [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review). Before you do please read the permissions documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3).